# Quartz line with a strange texture

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics, quartz-graphics, textures

Is it possible to draw a line with a strange  texture in Quartz?
This is an example of the texture.!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It somewhat depends on how you're drawing the line. Here's one option: Make an image containing the pattern you want, then create an UIColor using `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:]` and set that as the current stroke color and then draw a line.

Answer (score 0):

One approach: Draw diagonal lines (e.g. using `CGContextAddLineToPoint`) after clipping the rect (`CGContextClipToRect`).